# Error when trying to add a point to my score counter. Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, counter

I have an error that I have run into when trying to create my score counter for my lua game. Here is the code that I have.

```
score = 0

local playerScore = display.newText("Score" ..score, 0, 10, "AmericanTypewriter-Bold",          16);
playerScore:setTextColor(0, 0, 0);


playerScore.text = "Score: " .. score

function ball:touch( event )
if event.phase == "began" then
playerScore.text = playerScore.text + 1 
ball:applyForce(0, -10)
return true
end
end
```

Here is the line that gives me the error.

```
playerScore.text = playerScore.text + 1
```

The error that it gives me.

```
Attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'text' (a string value)
```

Comment: `playerScore.text = playerScore.text:gsub('%d+', function(x) return x+1 end)`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to add 1 to the string "Score: 1" (where 1 may be any number), instead you should increment the *score* variable and then update the text.

This should do the job.

```
score = score + 1
playerScore.text = "Score: " .. score
```